# Validate a JSON object containing a Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, validation, json.net

I'm working with JSON signatures for a number of objects in a .NET project, and later validating those objects to make sure they contain the proper number of arguments, etc.

However, I don't know how to validate this object, since "myActions" can contain a varying number of elements.  This example only has two, but there could be several more, or even just one (actually, it's always going to be anywhere from 1 to 5 elements).

```
{
    "myCanvas": {
        "width": 700,
        "height": 700,
        "initialScene": "scene1"
    },
    "myActions": {
        "actionOne": {
            "type": "web",
            "text": "Open our homepage.",
            "params": {
                "linkUri": "http://your.server.name/"
            }
        },
        "actionTwo": {
            "type": "web",
            "text": "Show item.",
            "params": {
                "linkUri": "http://your.server.name/items/123"
            }
        }
    },
    "otherStuff": {
        "controlBoard": {
            "format": [
            {
                "image": "image1",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 700,
                "h": 700
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I validate against this, since the JSON signature could come in one of five forms?  Could I refer to this as a Dictionary and validate it that way?  Right now, I'm using something like this (below) w/ a String.Format (hence all of the extra quotes and curly brackets), but I'm using this same giant signature inside of 5 nearly-identical objects, because I know that myActions will contain anywhere from 1 to 5 elements.  Keep in mind that I have no control on the format of the top JSON block; I'm only writing the validators (like the one below).  If "myActions" were an array, this would be a snap.

```
""myMetadata"":{{   
    ""myCanvas"":{{
        ""type"":""object"",
        ""required"":true,
        ""properties"":{{
            ""width"":{{
                ""type"":""number"",
                ""required"":true
            }},
            ""height"":{{
                ""type"":""number"",
                ""required"":true
            }},
            ""initialScene"":{{
                ""type"":""string"",
                ""required"":true
            }}
        }}
    }},
    ""myActions"":{{
        ""type"":""object"",
        ""required"":true,
        ""properties"":{{
            {0}
        }}
    }},
    ""otherStuff"":{{
        ""type"":""object"",
        ""required"":true,
        ""properties"":{{
            ""controlBoard"":{{
                ""type"":""object"",
                ""required"":true,
                ""properties"":{{
                    ""format"":{{  
                        ""type"":""array"",
                        ""items"":{{  
                            ""type"":""object"",
                            ""properties"":{{  
                                ""image"":{{  
                                    ""type"":""string"",
                                }},    
                                ""x"":{{  
                                    ""type"":""number"",
                                }},
                                ""y"":{{  
                                    ""type"":""number"",
                                }},
                                ""w"":{{  
                                    ""type"":""number"",
                                }},
                                ""h"":{{  
                                    ""type"":""number"",
                                }}
                            }}
                        }}
                    }}
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is feasible. Some JSON parsers/deserializers do support a couple distinct syntaxes for the purpose of deserializing into strongly typed dictionaries, as in your example (your first JSON snippet, that is).

I know mine does.

Among the most common syntaxes that map data into .NET dictionaries:

Either,

```
"SomeDictionary": [
    { "Key": "Key1", "Value": "Value1" },
    { "Key": "Key2", "Value": "Value2" },
    ...
 ]
```

Or, more straightforwardly, as in your case:

```
 "SomeDictionary": {
     "Key1": "Value1",
     "Key2": "Value2",
     ...
  }
```

(Where "Value1", "Value2", etc, don't need to be of primitive types, but can also be objects or lists/arrays, etc)

Your target object model (i.e., classes thereof) will thus look like something along the lines of:

```
public class MyParams
{
    public string linkUri { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class MyAction
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public MyParams @params { get; set; }
}

public class MyOuterObject
{
    // other properties omitted
    public IDictionary<string, MyAction> myActions { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

E.g., see:

(Sample object model)

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/blob/master/JsonTest/ParserTests.cs#L123

(Corresponding unit test)

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/blob/master/JsonTest/ParserTests.cs#L729

'Hope this helps,